# can the iphone prompt for a webclip with javascript?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to invoke the book mark action sheet in mobile safari through javascript?  Basically simulate the user pressing the "+" button.  Or better yet, touch a link in a web page and auto-add the webclip to your home screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has not exposed this functionality through a third party API (Javascript or Cocoa API).